# What is the "best practice" for converting an external API's data structure?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, angularjs

When an API's data structure does not fit well with an angular app, I am trying to determine the best-practice in my specific design and implementation for converting it to a usable structure.

I was doing this on an 'as needed' basis within the app controllers/directives, which quickly lead to spaghetti code.

Now I'm thinking this belongs in the service/factory which interacts with the API. Are there drawbacks or benefits to the Factory pattern over a more service oriented architecture when it comes to handling data structure conversion?

Comment: This seems like far too generic a question.  The right structure for sending data to an API depends upon a whole lot of things that are specific to the data, the application, how the data is normally consumed, how the data is transmitted and the specific API function, etc...  For example, a Javascript API takes arguments and objects with properties, but a REST API requires most things in string form which may mean JSON.

Comment: I'm not asking what specific structure I should use. I'm asking how/where it should be handled.

Comment: What do you mean "where it should be handled"?  The consumer of the API constructs the arguments to an API function themselves.  The implementor of the API processes the arguments as the specific implementation sees fit.  I guess I don't understand what question you're asking.  I'm thinking you need to provide an explicit example that shows several options you might be asking about.

Comment: "how/where it should be handled... as in should it be converted to a more useful structure in the service/factory, or should the app be structured to fit the data, or something else. Just added a line to the question to include this.

Comment: Again, this is too generic a question.  The app should structure its data in what makes the most sense for the app.  There are many considerations that go into determining what makes the most sense.  How the data must be organized for communicating with an API is only one of those considerations.  How the data is used within the app is likely more important, but is just yet another consideration.  How the data is stored persistently (if stored persistently) is yet another consideration, security might be another consideration and so on...

Comment: [Why was my question closed as too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6490/)

Comment: I disagree. This is a perfectly sensible question with a less than perfect phrasing, which has attracted a perfectly good answer. I would vote to leave open, if I could.

Comment: @david.pfx: You have access to the close review queue, and you can vote to leave open there.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: How? it's not searchable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @david.pfx: No, the queue is not searchable, so you have to hit the question as you work your way through the queue. Unfortunately, you can't cast a "don't close"-vote on the question.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: That's what I thought. There have been a couple of times I wanted to, which is when I leave this kind of comment.

Comment: @david.pfx: It was your "if I could" that triggered my comment. Just a comment that you disagree with the close votes/reason and an explanation why is usually enough for me to take a second look at the question before casting my vote while reviewing.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I got the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Yours is a common-enough problem that the solution is has a name:  an [anticorruption layer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AnticorruptionLayer).  This is a layer that translates between an external API with an undesirable structure and the desired internal structure of your app.  The idea is to limit the "corruption" of the undesired structure to as small a part of your code as possible.

The external API doesn't have to be bad in an absolute sense, just not ideally suited for your particular application.  If you can think of a better API, by all means go for it.  The earlier you do, the cleaner your code will be.